# Eclipse: have the same file open in two editors?

Tags: eclipse

When I'm editing a large file, I often want to have it open in two editing windows at once (eg. for reference, or because I'm working on two different parts of the file at once).

Is there any way to do this with Eclipse?

Answer (score 299, accepted):

Open your file and then `Window`->`New Editor` *(Note: in newer versions it will be called `New Window`)*

Then, click on its tab and drag it somewhere else to have two editors of the same file

Update: as mentioned by moschlar, From version 4.4, two editors can be created with `Window` -> `Editor` -> `Clone`.

Comment: This is the only solution that works in Eclipse Juno, since the 'New Editor' option seems to be removed from the editor tab context menu.

Comment: This option is inactive for me. Do you understand why?

Comment: Janusz, see moschlar's comment.

Comment: The other options in the Window -> Editor menu are useful too,
I usually go for the "Toggle Split Editor (Vertical)" one.

Comment: I am running Oxygen and "New Editor" doesn't seem to do it.  Instead it, ahem, opens a new Window with nothing in it.  However, Window->Editor->"Toggle Split Editor", either vertical or horizontal, works for me.

Comment: What happens if you actually edit (not just view) this file in more than one editor at once? Which version will be saved?

Comment: This allows to use the same `*.sql` file with two different database connections in the SQL Editor.

Answer (score 85):

In Eclipse Luna (4.4) and above, this is supported out of the box: `Window -> Editor -> Clone`.

Answer (score 21):

I realize he specified a new editing window. Showing an alternative for those, like me, that do not want a new editor but would like to be able to look at the file in two places at the same time in the same tab.

`Window -> Editor -> Toggle Split Editor` will split the editor horizontally or vertically.
`Ctrl + _` is horizontal and `Ctrl + {` is vertical. More precisely it's `Ctrl + Shift + -` and `Ctrl + Shift + [`.

I had issues with it in Mars (see note below) that seem to have cleared up in Neon.

**Mars Note:** The split editor seems a bit buggy. The JavaScript editor likes to jump the cursor to the other pane momentarily when it does a while-you-type-validation.

Comment: I was looking for this functionality, and found 2 suitable options in this post (split & clone)!   Referring to your note, do you find the cloned editor solution to work better/more consistently than toggling split?  One being as stable as the other I'd prefer your method (split) so I don't have 2 separate tabs open for the same file--get confusing with Files/Class names that are similar.

Comment: In Mars, the clone is the way to go. I haven't tried it in Neon yet.

Answer (score 10):

Right click on your editor tab and select "New Editor".

... unless you have a newer version of eclipse, in which case do Window -> New Editor.

Comment: @ChristopherStock on `Eclipse-Juno`, you can open `Window -> New Editor`. I've tested on my eclipse juno! :D

Comment: That's right. This solution works in all Eclipse versions. It's a pity, that this option has been removed in the right-click / context-menu of the tab.. But never mind! :) Eclipse FTW!! :D

Answer (score 3):

Window -> Editor -> Clone is also available in Neon 2 and, judging from the other comments seems to be available in all newer Eclipses.

It's my preferred solution.

Answer (score 3):

In order to keep answers up to date i underline that with Eclipse STS this action is performed using `window -> Editor -> Toggle split editor (horizental) | Toggle split editor (vertical)`

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse **Mars** there is another way of doing it:

`Window -> Editor -> Clone`.

then drag the cloned tab to the corner to create a parallel window.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to now be in the File-> New View Into File which opens the tab with focus into a new tab in the same group where you can then drag it to another group if you wish.