# How to enable duplicate tabs in Eclipse? (i.e. duplicate windows)

Tags: eclipse, window

If there's one thing I miss about emacs it's having 4 windows of the same file open, each at a different location in that file, for super quick referencing. Is there a way to get Eclipse to present multiple tabs of the same file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse: have the same file open in two editors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058784/eclipse-have-the-same-file-open-in-two-editors)

Comment: Starting with Eclipse Luna 4.4 M4+, you will be able to split your editor twice, for a single file. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20567138/6309).

Answer (score 92, accepted):

On the `Window` menu choose `Editor`, then `Clone` (since 4.4.x) or `New Editor` (earlier versions). You can then drag the title bar around to get side-by-side views.

Answer (score 13):

Another way would be to **split the code editor view twice**

But this will only be possible with Eclipse Luna 4.4 M4, as detailed by Lars Vogel in "[Split editor implemented in Eclipse M4 Luna](http://blog.vogella.com/2013/12/12/split-editor-implemented-in-eclipse-m4-luna-solves-bug-8009-one-of-the-highest-voted-bug-in-eclipse-platform/)", in [Bug 8009](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8009):

> The split editor functionality has been developed in [Bug 378298](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378298), and will be available as of Eclipse Luna M4. The Note & Newsworthy of Eclipse Luna M4 will contain the announcement.
>   Current shortcut for splitting is:
>
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>_</kbd> for **split horizontally**, and
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd> for **split vertically**.

Depending on your keyboard layout:

- [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1599699/andrew) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834594/how-to-enable-duplicate-tabs-in-eclipse-i-e-duplicate-windows/20567138?noredirect=1#comment73712596_20567138) that you can need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> .
- [el-teedee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/912046/el-teedee) mentions (also [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834594/how-to-enable-duplicate-tabs-in-eclipse-i-e-duplicate-windows/20567138?noredirect=1#comment96349199_20567138)) that, when pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd> in my Javascript editor, it inserts `''`.
  To fix this, I need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALTGR</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd> (Linux Ubuntu French keyboard),

[image: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=238285]

Comment: Unfortunately (in Mars.1 aka 4.5.1 at least) the actual functionality is "Toggle split editor".  So doing it more than once simply closes the extra editor tabs that the previous action had opened.  It's still possible to clone a tab and drag it around, but the user still gets the ugly extra "tab bar" that way.

Comment: @TiStrga Do you know if the issue persists in Neon? (4.6, https://eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php, currently in RC3)

Comment: I do not know, sorry.  Mars.1 is the only installation I have at the moment.

Comment: Note that you have to press Ctrl + Shift.

Comment: @Andrew Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: when pressing `CTRL+{` in my Javascript editor, it inserts `''`, to fix this, I need press `CTRL+ALTGR+{` (Linux Ubuntu French keyboard), then vertical split works

Comment: @el-teedee Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, just right-click on the editor tab you want, and select "New Editor". It'll create a new tab editing the same file. You can then drag this new tab to the left or right edge of the view to get them in a "split screen" state. It's really very flexible.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Right-click tab > New Editor.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers explain how to open multiple editors or split editor. If we are talking about other tabs/views that are not editor, it depends on the implementation.

**TLDR**: search for pin toggle [image: pin toggle] or create new view button/option in view!

**History view, Search view** and other pinnable tabs - have "Pin this XXX View" toggle:
[image: Search view with pin button]

[image: History view with pin button]
If you pin it it will keep the content and new Search (or history show) will show in new history view.

**History view** also has "Reuse Compare Editor" option so compares can be opened in same or separate tabs:
[image: Reuse compare editor option in History view]

**Markers view** has option "New Markers View":
[image: Markers view options]
This view can be named and you can set custom filter for each view.
Similar is **"Terminal View"** that has button to open new terminal view:
[image: Terminal view button for new terminal]

Some tabs do not have any option to be duplicated. Tested with Eclipse 2019-12 (4.14.0)

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem, but not with the main edit tabs: I wanted to have duplicate tabs in additional view panel (exactly: two junit views to compare different test runs).

In my case the only possible way to achive such thing was creating separate window: `Window` > `New Window` and openning new view there.

p.s. I'm using eclipse kepler 4.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

For eclipse kepler , you can try right-click > open-with > any other like text editor

Answer (score 0):

select window menu, then editor option, then clone