# How can I duplicate a non-editor panel in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, window, panel

I had exactly the same problem another user ([arghtype](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2417043/arghtype)) is having [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22908815/1091943) in this question's thread: [How to enable duplicate tabs in Eclipse? (i.e. duplicate windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834594/how-to-enable-duplicate-tabs-in-eclipse-i-e-duplicate-windows/22908815#22908815)
Although, it is only an answer post that doesn't necessarily achieve what we both want.
It recommends opening a separate, duplicated window, which is a bit resource heavy for what I need.

I wanted to formally ask this question in case anyone has the appropriate answer instead of a work-around or compromise, or we can open a feature request in the Eclipse work item tracker, and this way the answer and any history can become more apparent for this specific issue.
Also note I have tried the Menu options "Window" > "Show View" > "Other...", and then have selected the view/panel I wanted, with the current one in my UI both selected and unselected in different cases, and I still do not receive a duplicate panel.

I would also appreciate sources such as links to any documentation, or at least a screen shot with an answer, since I am very carefully **not** asking about the editor panel in the UI, which is commonly found as an issue on the internet.

To add, my specific case is using RTC 5.0.2 with Eclipse 4.2.2 (Juno), and I would like 
multiple "Work Items" panels open for my workflow.  One for overall reference, one for current, immediate work, and any more for what have you.

Another related source I found that all seem to speak about the similar, more prevalent issue, specifically concerning only the editor tab/panel:
[How do you split a window/view in Eclipse IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471578/how-do-you-split-a-window-view-in-eclipse-ide)

**Edit:**
I have opened an Eclipse Bug/Enhancement request for the UI here: [Bug 471001 - Allow user to create duplicate panels in perspective view](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471001).
We will see how it is handled.  Either my version is too old to have this feature, or it does not exist, and could prospectively be added.

Comment: With Eclipse Luna you can drag editors to get multiple tabs shown at once - but that was new in Luna.

Comment: @greg-449 I believe you are still referring to 'editors', which may be a panel/view, but that is the only one I have seen that I can duplicate so far.  I stated I would like to duplicate other panels, with more examples such as Progress, Problems, and so on.

Comment: Well it that case it is entirely an RTC issue as those are not Eclipse items

Comment: @greg-449 I mentioned the other panels that should be available in a standard/basic Eclipse install without any other additional plug-ins.  I have also tried these in my client, looked through the menu items and right-click context menu, and still do not see this option.
I also believe that these panels inherit a common interface, so they should all have this option, when they are not specifically en editor panel, or or they will all not have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far without a firm answer, I have opened an Eclipse Bug/Enhancement request for the UI here: [Bug 471001 - Allow user to create duplicate panels in perspective view](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471001).
We will see how it is handled.  Either my version is too old to have this feature, or it does not exist, and could prospectively be added.